# pandas calculate/show dataframe cumsum() only for positive values and other condition

Tags: python, pandas

How to make this `cumsum()` calculate and show values on new column rows only when `df.col_2 == 'closed'` and `df.col_values > 0` :

`df['new_col'] = df.groupby('col_1')['col_values'].cumsum()`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a solution (but there might be a more elegant one):

```
indexes = (df.col_2 == 'closed') & (df.col_values > 0)
df.loc[indexes, 'new_col'] = df.loc[indexes].groupby('col_1')['col_values'].cumsum()
```